# Using recursion in non static method - C#

Tags: c#, recursion

I am a bit confused about calling recursive method from itself.
Here is a sample code:

```
class Program
{
 public static void main(String args[]) 
 {
  Program p = new Program();
  p.Foo();
  }

  Public ... Foo()
  {
   Foo(); 
  }
```

Do i need to create new instance of Program to call Foo from Foo?
My code works without the instance but I am not sure if its correct.

Thanks

Comment: No, you don't need to create another instance. 
method `Foo` runs in the context of your current instance, so naturally, when you call `Foo` from inside it, you don't need to specify the instance.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to make a new instance of `Program`, but onlu of you declare your `Foo` method as `static`. If you keep it as it is, you will need to make a new instance of `Program`, which I suggest you not to, because it is not a good practice to have a class which instantiate itself in a static method, only to call a nonstatic method. You should have:

```
class Program
{
 public static void main(String args[]) 
 {
  Foo(); //direct call to Foo 
 }

  public static ... Foo()
  {
   Foo(); 
  }
 }
```

Comment: @SushilMate why do you say that?

Comment: @SushilMate this code will not work as it is, of course, it is just a way of saying public static...Foo, but of course it will not run.

Comment: of course. some advice on your solution would help OP to proceed in right direction. with this approach he will get stackoverflow exception.

Comment: @SushilMate this is just a way of marking recursivity, It does not have a return anywhere, so it may be caught in an endless loop, and after a while, of course it will cause stackoverflow. But this may not be the form he will use recursivity, because it would be meaningless.

Answer (score 0):

No, you do not have to create a new class. Here is an (unittest) example.

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace UnitTestProject
{
    [TestClass]
    public class UnitTest
    {
        public class Factorial
        {
            Dictionary<int, long> store = new Dictionary<int, long>();

            public long Get(int number)
            {
                if (store.ContainsKey(number))
                {
                    return store[number];
                }

                if (number == 0)
                {
                    store.Add(0, 1);
                    return 1;
                }

                var result = number * Get(number - 1);
                store.Add(number, result);

                return result;
            }
        }


        [TestMethod]
        public void SomeTest()
        {
            // Arrange
            var target = new Factorial();
            var results = new List<long>();

            // Act
            for (int i = 10; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                results.Add(target.Get(i));
            }

            // Assert
        }
    }
}
```